# ORMLite many to many relation

Tags: android, many-to-many, dao, ormlite

In order to make a many to many relation between these two class with ORMLite :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "test1")
public class Test1 {
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<Test2> test2Collection;
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "test2")
public class Test2 {
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<Test1> test1Collection;
}
```

I'm facing to the problem that ORMLite at the tables creation, don't know about the Foreign Keys between this class..

In order to make this relation do I have to add a single `ForeignDatabaseField` on each class like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "test1")
public class Test1 {
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Test2 test2;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<Test2> test2Collection;
}
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "test2")
public class Test2 {
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Test1 test1;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<Test1> test2Collection;
}
```

It seems to be a strange way?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.  How would you represent the ownership of a `Test2` being associated with a a collection of `Test1` without some shared information?

Comment: yes I need the Foreign Key linked to the second object primary key. So it was I've done in my second example ..?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to make this relation do I have to add a single ForeignDatabaseField on each class like that:

With a many-to-many relationship, the best way to associate objects together is with a "join table".  In your case, there would be a 3rd table named `Test1Test2Join` or something.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "test1test2join")
public class Test1Test2Join {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Test1 test1;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Test test2;
}
```

For more information, see the [many-to-many example](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/jdbc/examples/manytomany).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this (his second example) *can't work for a many to many relationship*. To make a one to many relationship from Test1 to Test2, Test2 can have as many Test1 objects as it wants, but every Test1 object has to have a reference to the Test2 that contains them. Now, you want to do the same in the other direction: Test1 contains multiple Test2 objects. However, Test2 can only reference one Test1 object that contains it through it's `private Test1 test1` field (since you can't use the collection for that). Yay or nay?

Comment: Yeah, this answer makes no sense @Rauter.  I've rewritten it.  Thanks.

Comment: Example link is broken, try this: https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html#Examples